# std::unique_ptr cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm currently trying to struggle my way through converting raw points to `std::unique_ptr`.  The only thing I don't understand is why this code doesn't work:

```
auto it = entities.begin();
while (it != entities.end()) {
    int index = getIndex((*it)->getAABB());
    if (index != -1) {
        children.at(index)->insert(std::move(*it)); // Error
        it = entities.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        it++;
    }
}
```

And entities is:

```
typedef std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<QuadTreeObject>> EntityContainer;
EntityContainer entities;
```

The error says `std::unique_ptr cannot be referenced, it is a deleted function.`

Comment: Are you sure that's the entire error message? It seems incomplete.

Comment: I suspect this has more to do with the fact that `std::unique_ptr` is movable but not copyable.

Comment: What type is `children`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store `unique_ptr`s in an `unordered_set` and get them out again.

Access while in the container is `const` so your `move` does nothing.

The lack of transparent hash functions makes finding elements difficult as well.